# ReferenceError: providers is not defined [Getting the following error when i am trying to use Ether.js to get block number]

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, ethers.js, ethereumjs

```
var url = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<my-api-key>';
var customHttpProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url);

async function displayblock()
{
    var block = await providers.getBlockNumber();
    console.log(block);
}
displayblock();
```

I am using the above code to fetch the block number from mainet, but it throws the following error.

```
**        var block = await providers.getBlockNumber();
                ^

ReferenceError: providers is not defined
    at displayblock (C:\Users\Pratik Jussal\OneDrive\Desktop\BLOCKCHAIN\Ether.js\Blockchain.js:7:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pratik Jussal\OneDrive\Desktop\BLOCKCHAIN\Ether.js\Blockchain.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 **
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Friendly advise: you should not post your API keys in public forums.

Comment: Hey thanks Sanjay, I realized my mistake after a while. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
var block = await providers.getBlockNumber();
```

But providers variable is not defined here. You should be able to understand this from the error. Here is a working code (ethers ver: 5.6.8) for you

```
const ethers = require("ethers");

const url = "<Your URL goes here>";
const customHttpProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url);

async function displayblock() {
  const blockNumber = await customHttpProvider.getBlockNumber();
  console.log(blockNumber);
}
displayblock();
```